# Which language and framework would you use to develop the biggest websites mid 2017?

Tags: frameworks, scalability, high-availability

If you were to start programming the following websites in may 2017, which language and framework would you use and why?(Still assuming the huge amount of users these websites have)

There is an overwhelming amount of technologies(C++, python, java, golang, node.js, spring, play framework, treefrog, django, the list goes on and on forever) available to build web applications right now. If you ask online, people will say there's no best programming language or framework. By knowing which technology would be used for the major websites I know which of the languages and frameworks are more suited when taken to the extreme cases of the most used websites. These are interesting case studies because we all know a little bit what each of these websites requires.

- Google Search
- Youtube
- Facebook
- Instagram
- Amazon
- LinkedIn
- StackOverflow

I guess when taking any application to extremes the best technologies are the ones that are nearer to hardware. So most probably C++ and Golang would be the best option to all of these applications considering only resource management. Am I wrong? Would anyone advocate using node.js to build Facebook and Instagram due to their event-driven nature? I don't think so, but please correct me with I'm wrong.

Comment: I think this question belongs in software recommendations site not stack overflow.

Comment: I disagree. There's a lot of questions here that do not dive into code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on what you wanna do. Different technology stack has its own advantage. You might want to get a bit more clear about the requirements.

Comment: I added an explanation to my question

Comment: That's precisely what I want to know. I've given you the requirements since you already know what all the major websites need. If you know the differences between all programming languages and frameworks, then you are able to point out the best ones for the websites I asked about.